# How to use Console.SetWindowSize(); on Linux using .Net Core?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, console

I'm currently working on some fancy console app. I'm using .Net Core 2.1. It was all fine, when I was working on Windows, but then I wanted to test it on Linux and use that glorious "cross-platform". To be specyfic I was using that:

```
System.Console.SetWindowSize();
```

And them...

`Exception has occurred: CLR/System.PlatformNotSupportedException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in System.Console.dll: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'
   at System.ConsolePal.SetWindowSize(Int32 width, Int32 height)`

So... Yeah `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`. Not so "cross-platform". But I was using some win console API etc. My question is:

Is there any workaround or some 3rd party lib, which will work on Linux? Or maybe I'm should use in diffrent?

Comment: [Related Issue on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31915). Also from the link: you could try to p/invoke `ioctl(TIOCSWINSZ)` (google for it).

Comment: Sure, I'll check this!

Comment: "Not so 'cross-platform'" Nothing is a god that makes everything work properly on each platform. The terminal size is controlled by the terminal. It is very easy to assume it uses the windows command prompt on windows, but not exactly on linux

Comment: Whether you can control the terminal size depends on the terminal emulator not the OS. There are all kinds of terminal emulators on linux (also on windows but they are supposed to be compatible with windows command prompt) to support, or there is even no GUI environment running, or for the most common situation, the server is accessed via SSH, how could the application at the remote side control the local terminal?

Comment: BTW, learn how a console application works with terminal before sneering at anything. It was your own problem, not .NET Core. SO is for asking and answering questions, not for you to taunt

Comment: I'm actually familiar with terminal emulator and windows CommandLine and PowerShell. My point was, that lib (`Console`) is in `.Net Stadard` and `.Net Core`, so it should work independent from platform. Maybe they should just deprecate this methods, maybe not. They probably have bigger issues than some forgotten method. But still it's not fully "cross-platform" if you have windows-only libs packed with .Net Core

Comment: This method still exists and there is still no work-around? What a pity..

Comment: At least now we get a warning if we try to call this method: *"This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Console.SetWindowSize(int, int)' is only supported on: 'windows'"*. And if we wrap this call in an OS check, we can get rid of the warning: `if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows()) { Console.SetWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight); }`. Sucks that these methods arent available in linux, but at least we get some warnings about trying to use it.