# .NET Core console resize event in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, console, command-line-interface

Any chances to be notified about console resize in Linux? I actually would like to prevent text wrapping on resize, so looking for redrawing the clipped content.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894813/how-to-use-console-setwindowsize-on-linux-using-net-core. The answer is the same as that one: you can't, not in a supported and cross platform way.

Comment: @omajid My question is the opposite of that one :) It's not about setting the size, and I am not looking to be cross-platformed. Some interop calls would probably do it, as it is possible for, let's say, Midnight Commander.

Comment: have you tried polling `Console.WindowWidth` and `Console.WindowHeight`?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann That would work, but I am looking for a less obtrusive approach then polling.

Comment: @DmitryNogin don't see any other approach right now. wrap it in class and some tasks, and you can make yourself an event provider that you start and just let running in the background